# How to get comment Node ID of a discussion in GitHub Action with GitHub GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, github-actions, github-api, github-graphql

I'm working on a GitHub Action triggered on the comment of a certain discussion (say `org/repo/discussions/6#discussioncomment-7349183`) being created or edited. I'd like the action to reply the comment like "your pipeline is running here" with a link.

Then I found that [there's only GraphQL way to add a reply](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/4327) like:

```
mutation {
  addDiscussionComment(input:{  
    discussionId: "D_something",
    replyToId: "DC_something_", 
    body: "Test reply", 
  }) {
    clientMutationId
    comment {
      id
      body  
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to get the Node ID of the comment with `github.event.comment.id` in the pipeline and use it as `replyToId`, but `comments` only accepts these arguments:

```
after: String
Returns the elements in the list that come after the specified cursor.

before: String
Returns the elements in the list that come before the specified cursor.

first: Int
Returns the first n elements from the list.

last: Int
Returns the last n elements from the list.
```

Which means I'll use a query like:

```
{
  repository(owner: "org", name: "repo") {
    discussion(number: 6) {
      comments(first: 1) {
        nodes {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However I don't know the position of `github.event.comment.id` as the triggerer is not guaranteed to be the last comment.

Could you please show me how to get the comment's Node ID?

---

My temporary walkaround is to get the `id` and `url` of the first 100 comments, and search for the `url` ending with `github.event.comment.id`, the corresponding `id` is the Node ID I need. Is there any cleaner & better solution?